# How to load image into layer-item with glide

Tags: android, user-interface, android-xml, android-glide

I need an `imageView` with a custom shape in my application. And 
I created my shape with a `layer-list` in drawable.

this is my `layer-list` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logo">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/temp_image"
                android:gravity="center" android:alpha="1"/>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-150dp"
          android:bottom="120dp"
          android:left="0dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="130%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorBottomMenuDark"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This works well But I need to load images into a bitmap(item with log id) dynamically with [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not load the images via glide in the item defined in LayerList in the direct way.

Though you can do something like below by setting up drawable programmatically.

```
//Drawable you want to set
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.image7, null);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list, null);
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.logo, drawable);
RL.setBackground(layerDrawable);
```